# AWS Lambda Hello World Example Typescript: "sam local invoke" gives Error: Cannot find module 'app'

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy an AWS Lambda function with `sam` using AWS's Hello World Example Typescript template, and the example template is not working.

I am pretty sure this is a bug in AWS.

This is very easy to replicate:

I am in an EC2 instance with ubuntu. Just run:

```
sam init
```

and follow this configuration:

```
Which template source would you like to use?
        1 - AWS Quick Start Templates
        2 - Custom Template Location
Choice: 1

Choose an AWS Quick Start application template
        1 - Hello World Example
        2 - Multi-step workflow
        3 - Serverless API

        ...

Template: 1

Use the most popular runtime and package type? (Python and zip) [y/N]: N

Which runtime would you like to use?
        1 - aot.dotnet7 (provided.al2)
        2 - dotnet6
        3 - dotnet5.0
        4 - dotnetcore3.1
        5 - go1.x
        6 - go (provided.al2)
        7 - graalvm.java11 (provided.al2)
        8 - graalvm.java17 (provided.al2)
        9 - java11
        10 - java8.al2
        11 - java8
        12 - nodejs18.x
        13 - nodejs16.x
        14 - nodejs14.x
        15 - nodejs12.x

Runtime: 14

What package type would you like to use?
        1 - Zip
        2 - Image
Package type: 1

Based on your selections, the only dependency manager available is npm.
We will proceed copying the template using npm.

Select your starter template
        1 - Hello World Example
        2 - Hello World Example TypeScript
Template: 2

Would you like to enable X-Ray tracing on the function(s) in your application?  [y/N]: N

Would you like to enable monitoring using CloudWatch Application Insights?
For more info, please view https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-application-insights.html [y/N]: N

Project name [sam-app]: 

    -----------------------
    Generating application:
    -----------------------
    Name: sam-app
    Runtime: nodejs14.x
    Architectures: x86_64
    Dependency Manager: npm
    Application Template: hello-world-typescript
    Output Directory: .
    Configuration file: sam-app/samconfig.toml
    
    Next steps can be found in the README file at sam-app/README.md
```

Now we get this template:

```
ubuntu@ip-111-31-16-16:~/MyAPP/lambda$ tree sam-app/
sam-app/
├── README.md
├── events
│   └── event.json
├── hello-world
│   ├── app.ts
│   ├── jest.config.ts
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── tests
│   │   └── unit
│   │       └── test-handler.test.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── samconfig.toml
└── template.yaml

4 directories, 9 files
```

Now if I go into `/sam-app` and just run:

```
ubuntu@ip-111-31-16-16:~/MyAPP/lambda/sam-app$ sam local invoke --event events/event.json
```

I get this error: `Error: Cannot find module 'app'`; the full message is here:

```
ubuntu@ip-111-31-16-16:~/MyApp/lambda/sam-app$ sam local invoke --event events/event.json
Invoking app.lambdaHandler (nodejs14.x)
Local image was not found.
Removing rapid images for repo public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs14.x
Building image..............................................................................................................................................................
Using local image: public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14-rapid-x86_64.

Mounting /home/ubuntu/MyApp/lambda/sam-app/hello-world as /var/task:ro,delegated, inside runtime container
START RequestId: 4a6ba3fe-f24c-4f10-9840-e66c2abafc50 Version: $LATEST
2023-04-10T18:13:12.492Z        undefined       ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'app'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/Runtime.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'app'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/Runtime.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:225:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:300:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:34)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
10 Apr 2023 18:13:12,511 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 129 InvokeID=
2023-04-10T18:13:12.641Z        undefined       ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'app'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/Runtime.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'app'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/Runtime.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:225:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:300:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:34)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
END RequestId: 2865c9f0-be40-47a2-b050-796ebd0aeaec

REPORT RequestId: 2865c9f0-be40-47a2-b050-796ebd0aeaec  Init Duration: 0.65 ms  Duration: 472.07 ms     Billed Duration: 473 ms Memory Size: 128 MB   Max Memory Used: 128 MB

{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'app'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/Runtime.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","trace":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'app'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/Runtime.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:225:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:300:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:34)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
```

Note that in the `sam init` step, in this step:

```
Select your starter template
        1 - Hello World Example
        2 - Hello World Example TypeScript
Template: 2
```

If only I had chosen 1 instead of 2, and keep everything else the same, I would not get this error. I would get a successfully-run test message.

What the hell, AWS?

Comment: "Runtime: nodejs14.x" - Node 14 hits end of life in under three weeks. You probably want to use something more supported.

Comment: @Quentin  I used "Runtime: nodejs18.x" as well, but the result is the same.

Comment: You are just missing the transpilation part which is not done by the sam cli tool. tsc app.ts inside the hello-world folder should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the hello-world app following the steps you shared while creating sam app successfully.

I have used **nodejs18.x** and do make sure docker engine is running locally.

Additional things I did.

1. Using terminal, get inside sam-app/hello-world and run `npm install`
2. Once node_modules are installed, run `tsc app.ts` to compile. This will create app.js file.
3. Then run `cd ..` to go parent folder where you have template.yaml
4. Run `sam local invoke --event events/event.json`.

**Command log below**

```html
user@0.0.0.0 ts-helloworld % sam local invoke --event events/event.json
Error: Running AWS SAM projects locally requires Docker. Have you got it installed and running?
user@0.0.0.0  ts-helloworld % sam local invoke --event events/event.json
Invoking app.lambdaHandler (nodejs18.x)
Image was not found.
Removing rapid images for repo public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs18.x
Building image...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Skip pulling image and use local one: public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs18.x:rapid-1.66.0-x86_64.

Mounting /Users/user/app-repos/sam-ts-helloworld/ts-helloworld/hello-world as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: 47d04232-46f5-4c6c-89da-f0ec3eb66033 Version: $LATEST
{"statusCode":200,"body":"{\"message\":\"hello world\"}"}END RequestId: 47d04232-46f5-4c6c-89da-f0ec3eb66033
REPORT RequestId: 47d04232-46f5-4c6c-89da-f0ec3eb66033  Init Duration: 2.26 ms  Duration: 1069.46 ms    Billed Duration: 1070 ms        Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 128 MB
```